# How to transform cron expression to json format using java

Tags: java, json, cron

I am trying to transform cron expression to JSON format. I have following "0 10 14-15 L * WED,SUN" which means:
run every 10 minute every hour between 14 and 15 last day of month at Wednesday and Sunday days
What I'm trying to get is like:

```
**seconds = {
  "exactSecondToRun": 0,
  "eachXSecondRun": 
 },
 minutes = {
  "exactMinuteToRun": 10,
  "eachXsecondRun":
 },
 hours = {
  "exactHourToRun":,
  "eachXHoursRun":,
  "fromHour":14,
  "toHour":15,
 },
  days = {
  "exactDayToRun": "L",
  "eachXDaysRun": ,
  "fromDay": ,
  "toDay": 
 },
  dayOfWeek = {
  "exactDOWToRu": ["WED","SUN"],
  "fromDOW": ,
  "toDOW":,
 },
  year = {
  "exactYearToRun": ,
  "eachXYearsRun": 30,
  "fromYear":10,
  "toYear":15,
 }**
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any library that directly converts cron expression to its JSON description. But what you can do is

1) Use a library like [cron-parser](https://github.com/grahamar/cron-parser) to convert cron expression to human readable string.

2) Write custom code to read this string and convert to a JSON

Sidenote: You can also take a look at source code of [cron-parser](https://github.com/grahamar/cron-parser) and resuse/enhance it to directly convert cron to json.